# Storing ONLY MONTH and DATE in a single Column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Hi I am trying to store Month and Date in a single column.

UseCase

I am dumping data into mysql for reporting purpose and report is monthly.

I will be using Hibernate later to retreive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear regarding the format you wish to use but assuming storing the month as a number followed by the date and separated by some sort of delimiter is OK then something like the following would do. Just the second INSERT statement actually does the storing you asked about.

*Having said that though, if you have the original data in a suitable format, I would suggest you use a single datetime column for storage and split it if necessary into month and date when you recover it later to use it.*

```
-- make a table to hold some dates
CREATE TABLE testdates ( thedate DATE DEFAULT NULL) ;

-- make a table to hold just the month and date in one column as requested
CREATE TABLE tbl_month_and_date (the_month_and_date VARCHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL ); 

-- put some dummy dates into the testdates table
INSERT INTO testdates (thedate)
VALUES
('2017-09-14'),
('2017-10-13'),
('2017-11-27'),
('2017-08-20');


-- insert the month and date into a single column in the tbl_month_and_date table
-- in this case separated my <space> <colon> <space>
INSERT INTO tbl_month_and_date (the_month_and_date)
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(thedate),' : ', thedate)
FROM testdates;

    -- show what is now in tbl_month_and_date
SELECT the_month_and_date
FROM tbl_month_and_date
```

The contents of table tbl_month_and_date are now

```
the_month_and_date  
9 : 2017-09-14      
10 : 2017-10-1      
11 : 2017-11-2      
8 : 2017-08-20
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use TIMESTAMP for repoting purpose instead of just Date, Month or both.